# Get USB key manufacturer serial number

Tags: windows, usb, batch, shell-script, serial

I am looking for a batch command to retrieve an USB key manufacturer serial number. I need a command that works in both Windows XP and Windows Seven.

This is for a hardware follow-up. I have a script that sends emails when a problem occurs and it needs to include a way to identify the removable disk.

At first I used `vol e:` but the number changes when the disk is formatted.

On several sites I saw `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` but it doesn't seem to work (at least on W7). The command returns `Invalid XML`.

This is not surprising. I ran `wmic diskdrive get /?` and the available options are:

```
Property                               Type                    Ope
========                                ====                    ===
Availability                            N/A                     N/A
BytesPerSector                          N/A                     N/A
Capabilities                            N/A                     N/A
CapabilityDescriptions                  N/A                     N/A
CompressionMethod                       N/A                     N/A
ConfigManagerErrorCode                  N/A                     N/A
ConfigManagerUserConfig                 N/A                     N/A
DefaultBlockSize                        N/A                     N/A
Description                             N/A                     N/A
DeviceID                                N/A                     N/A
ErrorCleared                            N/A                     N/A
ErrorDescription                        N/A                     N/A
ErrorMethodology                        N/A                     N/A
Index                                   N/A                     N/A
InstallDate                             N/A                     N/A
InterfaceType                           N/A                     N/A
LastErrorCode                           N/A                     N/A
Manufacturer                            N/A                     N/A
MaxBlockSize                            N/A                     N/A
MaxMediaSize                            N/A                     N/A
MediaLoaded                             N/A                     N/A
MediaType                               N/A                     N/A
MinBlockSize                            N/A                     N/A
Model                                   N/A                     N/A
Name                                    N/A                     N/A
NeedsCleaning                           N/A                     N/A
NumberOfMediaSupported                  N/A                     N/A
PNPDeviceID                             N/A                     N/A
Partitions                              N/A                     N/A
PowerManagementCapabilities             N/A                     N/A
PowerManagementSupported                N/A                     N/A
SCSIBus                                 N/A                     N/A
SCSILogicalUnit                         N/A                     N/A
SCSIPort                                N/A                     N/A
SCSITargetId                            N/A                     N/A
SectorsPerTrack                         N/A                     N/A
Signature                               N/A                     N/A
Size                                    N/A                     N/A
Status                                  N/A                     N/A
StatusInfo                              N/A                     N/A
SystemName                              N/A                     N/A
TotalCylinders                          N/A                     N/A
TotalHeads                              N/A                     N/A
TotalSectors                            N/A                     N/A
TotalTracks                             N/A                     N/A
TracksPerCylinder                       N/A                     N/A
```

No `SerialNumber`...

Do you have a better idea?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber` does seem to return multiple 40-digit numbers (one per drive) on Win7 x64.

Comment: Gosh... Why doesn't it work for me?!? What is the cause of the `Invalid XML` error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the solution on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287450/wmic-diskdrive-get-serialnumber-invalid-xml-output).

The SerialNumber property doesn't exist.

I now use:

`wmic diskdrive get PNPDeviceID`

But a fix exists from Microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2664203).